# How do I check my app's memory usage in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management

Is there an easy way to check how much memory is my application is currently using?

I need this to check if all of my objects are being destroyed correctly. My app's written in C++ with Qt.

Thanks!

Comment: you should check construction and deletion for your purpose.. in example on linux you can use valgrind..

Comment: You might also find the [`-widgetcount`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qapplication.html#QApplication) argument useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, especially if you have a complex application, you may want to use [valgrind](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-valgrind-overview.html). This is a tool designed for tracking memory allocation problems.

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything wrong with using `ps` or `top` on your terminal? What about using a debugger, such as `gdb`? Or are you looking to do something within your app with code?

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ps

http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_56.html

Comment: I need to do it with the code. I have a rather complex tree of objects, and I need to be able to destroy it all from the root element. I need to check the memory used before and after the procedure, something like this: `cout << memory used; rootItem.~destructor(); cout << memory used`